# Blue outlines on bootstrap select

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I have installed bootstrap-select and it all works fine, except that blue borders appear in  2 instances:

1) in the dropdown menu

[image]

2) when a new value is picked

[image]

Can someone please help how it can be fixed? I adjusted a few things already.

```css
.bootstrap-select .btn {
  height: 43px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.bootstrap-select .btn:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
outline: 0;
```

Should fix it, if you target the correct item.

Answer (score 4):

apply those two css rules after all the other css styles

```
.bootstrap-select .dropdown-toggle:focus {
    outline: none!important;
}
:focus {
  outline: none!important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Removing the blue outline around the element **and items inside of it:**

```
<style>
    .bootstrap-select .btn:focus {
        outline: none !important;
    }

    .selectpicker a {
        outline: 0;
    }
</style>
```

Tested on Chrome, Firefox and Opera.

Answer (score 1):

Add the css

```
.bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-menu li a {
  outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your css:

```
:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to the very bottom of my HTML was what finally worked for me on Chrome:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .bootstrap-select .dropdown-toggle:focus {
        outline: none !important;
        box-shadow: none !important;
    }
    :focus {
      outline: none !important;
      box-shadow: none !important;
    }
</style>
```

I think the key was that I was loading Bootstrap and other libraries after setting the CSS.